# Mahout's synthetic control data example

Tags: controls, mahout, synthetic

Mahout's wiki includes an example of using clustering on synthetic control data ([here](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/clustering-of-synthetic-control-data.html)).

The example includes a data sample with 100 rows of data for each of 6 patterns in the data. What I expect when I run the example code is that some of the clustering methods would provide better or worse clustering, but that they would more or less provide clusters grouping the 6 patterns.

That's not -- at all -- what I'm seeing when I run the examples. As a beginner, this is very confusing. Furthermore, since the data isn't normalized and the periods of the cyclic data don't match up, it's very hard to see how this raw data could *ever* cluster properly.

Am I missing something? Can a more experienced Mahout-er provide some orientation to what one should expect in this particular example?

I'm very interested in the scenario in which patterns in time-series data can be clustered. I have tried normalizing the data and using point-to-point deltas as the basis for clustering and gotten slightly better results. Does a more experienced Data analyst have suggestions for a better approach?